# Soft deleting with a relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a book and author table. A author has many books. A book has one author.

I wish to soft delete an author.

So I have a deleted_at field in the authors table (do I also need this on the books table?). There is also a author_id foreign key in the books table.

I call:

```
Author::destroy($id);
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I'm using larval 4.1

Here are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('authors', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('books', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
    $table->string('title'); // Varchar
    $table->string('isbn');  // Varchar
});
```

Comment: Just checking, do you also have the ``use SoftDeletingTrait;`` line in your ``Author`` model? Or ``protected $softDelete = true;`` for Laravel <4.2.

Comment: I have  protected $softDelete = true; as it's 4.1

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but does it work if you do ``Author::find($id)->delete();``?

Comment: @JoelHinz same error I'm afraid.

Comment: That sucks. :( Hope you find the error.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense because it looks as though it's actually deleting the row when it should be setting the `deleted_at` column.  Are you sure you have `protected $softDelete = true` in your `Author` model?  Foreign key constraints should have no bearing on this.

Comment: yes, protected $softDelete = true is there

Comment: Is this a laravel error or is it a SQL error? It sounds as though its an error from Mysql. Could you also include your mysql schema/laravel migration config.

Comment: The error type: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException". i'll update question with migrations.

Comment: What do you get if you do `try { Author::destroy($id) } 
catch(Illuminate\DatabaseQueryException $e) { echo $e->getSql(); exit; }`

Comment: @Unnawut I get: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought of cascaded deletes ?

```
//Suggested implementation , will this work ?
$table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->onDelete('cascade');

// my current implementation
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Does not work. I get the same error: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row:

Comment: Can you put the code for the two model classes Author and Book